# Next 13 with next-auth production build error

Tags: typescript, next.js13, next-auth

I am creating an application using next js version 13.5.5 and next-auth version 4.23. Now everything is working fine. Authentication and authorization are fully functional in the local environment. When I run the command to create a build for production it gives me this error.

```
Failed to compile.

./node_modules/@babel/runtime/regenerator/index.js
Dynamic Code Evaluation (e. g. 'eval', 'new Function', 'WebAssembly.compile') not allowed in Edge Runtime

Import trace for requested module:
./node_modules/@babel/runtime/regenerator/index.js
./node_modules/next-auth/react/index.js


Build failed because of webpack errors
   Creating an optimized production build
```